# How to post from a UWP client to a Laravel server?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, web-applications, uwp

I am trying to post to a Laravel server from a UWP client. The Laravel posting function and database work.

```
//route
Route::post('/text', 'Controller1@text');

//controller
public function text(Request $request){
$tag = new Tag;
$tag->title = $request->title;
$tag->save();
return redirect('/');
} 

//UWP:
var tag = new Tag() { title = "aTag" };
var tagJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tag);
Debug.WriteLine(tagJson);
var client = new HttpClient();
var HttpContent = new StringContent(tagJson);
HttpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
var responseContent = await client.PostAsync("***********/text", HttpContent);
```

The response status code is 500.

Comment: What do the Laravel logs say? I'm guessing that maybe the `jsonstruct` isn't correct. Maybe it's something like `{ "tag" : { "title" : "aTag" } }` which wouldn't work. Can you `dd($request)` from the controller method?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The request doesn't reach the controller, nothing is output to the log when called from the UWP app. When I call the post function from another Laravel page, it includes a token: <form method="post" action="{{ action('Controller1@text') }}"> {!! Form::token() !!}. Is that relevent?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the client app was trying to access a web route which requires a CSRF token. The route must be set in the api.php route file.